# Display sequence of words on BlackBerry screen

Tags: java, blackberry

I have ten words in a string array.  As an example: {"A B","C D","E F","G H"......}.
   I have to display these words in succession, holding each word on screen for 2 seconds. With each new word displayed, the font size needs to get smaller as well.

How do I do this on a BlackBerry?

Comment: Does the length of the word need to reduce by 2 characters each time? Is this regardless of the length of the first word?

Comment: no there is no need to reduce length. i have to reduce size of character that i used in String array

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Timer` to control the timing:

```
import java.util.Timer

int index;
String[] words;
```

...

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run()
    {
         // TODO: Check the bounds and kill the timer when we're done.

         // Invoke the code in the UI Thread
         UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run()
             {
                // Code to enumerate and concat the string...
             }
          });
     }
 };

timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 2000);
```

To change font size:

```
// in the class body:
final int minFontSize = 5;
int maxFontSize = minFontSize + words.length();

// in the timer's run method:
net.rim.device.api.ui.Font defaultFont = this.getFont();
net.rim.device.api.ui.Font myFont = defaultFont.derive(0, maxFontSize - index)

// change the font of the ui control
field.setFont(myFont);
```

I haven't checked the code to see if it compiles, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Like I said, I haven't really tested the code. But if you can post the error your get (while compiling or at runtime), then I can help you with it.